# Customised Bubble plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bubble-chart

I am trying to do a bubble plot. My data are:

```
Year<-rep(2001:2005, each = 5)
name<-c("John","Ellen","Mark","Randy","Luisa")
Name<-c(rep(name,5))
Value<-sample(seq(0,25,by=1),25)
mydata<-data.frame(Year,Name,Value)
```

And by far I've got to this point:

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(x=Year, y=Name, size = Value)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(axis.line = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_text(size=11,margin=margin(b=10),colour="black"),
        axis.text.y=element_text(size=13,margin=margin(l=10),colour="black",
                                 face="italic"),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.title=element_text(size=18,face="bold"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size=14),
        legend.title = element_text(size=18))
```

I need many modifications but I couldn't understand how to do that (I am not very familiar with ggplot2).
First, I would like to use the `viridis` scale, but neither `scale_color_viridis` nor `scale_fill_viridis` are working (I have also tried setting the `discrete=T` argument).

Second, I would like to avoid the 0 values to be plotted (i.e., having a blank space where the 0 value is being plotted), but neither using `na.omit` (e.g. as `ggplot(na.omit(mydata), aes(x=Year, y=Name, size = Value))` or as `ggplot(mydata, aes(x=Year, y=Name, size = na.omit(Value)))`) or removing the 0 from `Value` object work.

Third, I'd like the legend to be a continuous scale: the plotted values of `Value` are in a range from 1 to 25 (as I would like to remove the zeros) but the default legend is discrete with 5 points break.

I would like the plot to look more or less like this (with the bubble sizes depending on the value of `Value`):

[image: desired plot]

Any suggestions? Sorry for the many questions but I have some real difficulties in understanding how ggplot works. Thanks!

Comment: Just a thought: I recently had a similar idea to use a dot plot but then went with a relatively simple scatter plot switching two variables round which are in here this case your y-axis and legend (dot size). The thing is that you have two continuous variables and a third one which consists of your labels. To me it made much more sense to use a scatter plot and then use `geom_text()` to add the labels (Randy, Mark, etc.).

Comment: @FabianHabersack yes, actually I first started from a dot plot and then moved to a scatterplot, but ended up here! I guess now I just would like to see which one is more informative. And maybe using this opportunity to finally learn some ggplot tricks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to map a variable in your data to some scale, you use the `aes()` function to couple what ggplot2 calls an 'aesthetic' to an expression (typically a symbol for a column in your data). Thus, to make a colour scale, you have to specify a `colour` aesthetic inside the `aes()` function. In the code below, I also specify an `alpha` aesthetic, which is 1 if `Value > 0` and 0 otherwise, making the 0-value points completely transparent. I specify `I()` to let ggplot2 know that it should take this value literally instead of mapping it to a scale.

```r
library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.0.3

Year<-rep(2001:2005, each = 5)
name<-c("John","Ellen","Mark","Randy","Luisa")
Name<-c(rep(name,5))
Value<-sample(seq(0,25,by=1),25)
mydata<-data.frame(Year,Name,Value)

g <- ggplot(mydata, aes(x=Year, y=Name, size = Value)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = Value, 
                 alpha = I(as.numeric(Value > 0))))
```

Once we have specified the aesthetics, we can begin customising the scales. The typical pattern is `scale_{the aesthetic}_{type of scale}`, so we need to add `scale_colour_viridis_c()` if we want to map the colour values to the viridis scale (the `*_c` is for continuous scales). In the scales, we can specify for example the limits, which you've indicated should be between 1 and 25. Also, I added a `scale_size_area()` where we say that we do not want a legend for the size of the points by setting `guide = "none".

```r
g + scale_colour_viridis_c(option = "C", direction = -1,
                         limits = c(1, 25)) +
  scale_size_area(guide = "none") +
  theme(axis.line = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_text(size=11,margin=margin(b=10),colour="black"),
        axis.text.y=element_text(size=13,margin=margin(l=10),colour="black",
                                 face="italic"),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.title=element_text(size=18,face="bold"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size=14),
        legend.title = element_text(size=18))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-02-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: thanks a lot, this actually was the answer I preferred (and worked perfectly). And thank you for explaining each point, now it is definitely clearer! I like how you first set the general aesthetic and then pass to the single scales.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you are looking for?

```r
library(ggplot2)

Year<-rep(2001:2005, each = 5)
name<-c("John","Ellen","Mark","Randy","Luisa")
Name<-c(rep(name,5))
Value<-sample(seq(0,25,by=1),25)
Value <- ifelse(Value == 0, NA, Value)
mydata<-data.frame(Year,Name,Value)

ggplot(mydata, aes(x=Year, y=Name, size = Value, colour = Value)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_viridis_c() +
  scale_size(guide = F) +
  theme(axis.line = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_text(size=11,margin=margin(b=10),colour="black"),
        axis.text.y=element_text(size=13,margin=margin(l=10),colour="black",
                                 face="italic"),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.title=element_text(size=18,face="bold"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size=14),
        legend.title = element_text(size=18))
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

[image]

Concerning your points:
I did only see the `scale_colour_viridis_c` and the `scale_colour_viridis_b` functions which differ in the colors as far as I could see. Maybe I am missing some package?

Secondly regarding the `NA`s: you just needed to replace the 0s by `NA`s.

And lastly regarding the scale: The color-scale is automatically continuous. Depicting sizes continuously is a bit tricky, therefore it will always be discrete. But I removed it from the legend for you so that you only have the color there as in your example.

Comment: I actually just found out the different use of `_c`, `_d`, and `_b`: apparently, the difference is the use with discrete, continuous, or continuous (but binded) data - I thought it was related to the colours! https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_viridis.html
And thanks for the other two specifications, now is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternative way to think about this... maybe it's helpful. :-)

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)

df <- tibble(
  year = rep(2001:2005, each = 5),
  name = rep(c("John","Ellen","Mark","Randy","Luisa"),5),
  value = sample(seq(0,25,by=1),25)
)

df %>%
  mutate(name_2 = ifelse(year>2001 & year<2005, NA, name)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(year, value, group = name, label = name_2, color = name)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(vjust = -1) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
  theme_minimal(base_family = "serif") +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  xlab("")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! The fact is that I was trying to emulate something similar to this ( https://www.maartenlambrechts.com/assets/dotplot_eurostat.png ), only to realise that with my data it is probably not possible. I like your figure (and I should definitely start using tidyverse) but as I actually don't want to show a trend, maybe the lines represents an information that is a surplus. But I'll check it out!